# Composition of TailRec and State monad

Tags: scala, monads

To simplify my question, I'm going to start with an academic example, the ackermann function.

I use the following recursive naive implementation:

```
def a(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  if (m == 0) {
    n + 1
  } else if (m > 0 && n == 0) a(m - 1, 1)
  else a(m - 1, a(m, n - 1))
}
```

This is not optimal and ends quickly in stack overfow.
So I built a new implementation that uses TailRec from the standard scala library and that gives it that:

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

private[this] def a_impl(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): TailRec[BigInt] = {
  if (m == 0) {
    done(n + 1)
  } else if (m > 0 && n == 0) tailcall(a_impl(m - 1, 1))
  else
    for {
      x <- tailcall(a_impl(m, n - 1))
      y <- tailcall(a_impl(m - 1, x))
    } yield y

}

def a(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  a_impl(m, n).result
}
```

It works but is very slow. 
So I built a new implementation that uses the State monad, but again I lose the terminal recursion.

```
type Memo = Map[(BigInt, BigInt), BigInt]

private[this] def a_impl(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): State[Memo, BigInt] = {
  if (m == 0) {
    State.init(n + 1)
  } else {
    for {
      memoed <- State.gets { memo: Memo => memo get (m, n) }
      res <- memoed match {
        case Some(ack) => State.init[Memo, BigInt](ack)
        case None =>
          if (m > 0 && n == 0) for {
            a <- a_impl(m - 1, 1)
            _ <- State.update { memo: Memo => memo + ((m, n) -> a) }
          } yield a
          else for {
            a <- a_impl(m, n - 1)
            b <- a_impl(m - 1, a)
            _ <- State.update { memo: Memo => memo + ((m, n) -> b) }
          } yield b
      }
    } yield res
  }
}

def a(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  a_impl(m, n) eval (Map())
}
```

So my question is, how do I use both, State and TailRec?

I've seen the notion of Monad Transformer, but I don't really know how to use it in my example. 
I don't even know what kind of type to use, I have a choice between that and this:

```
type TailRecWithState = TailRec[State[Memo, BigInt]] 
// or  
type StateWithTailRec = State[Memo, TailRec[BigInt]]
```

Can you help me and point me in the right direction on this example (I would then manage on my practical case)?

Comment: When you say "really slow", how do you mean? What numbers are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: really slow is : 8 minutes on my laptop for computing a(4, 2)

Comment: One important point to note: your memoization doesn't do what you think it does. Since the state is immutable, computation results aren't shared across computation branches.

Comment: my implementation with State is efficient and fast. a(3,9) is computed in 8ms instead of 2s for the TailRec one. But the State one is unable to compute a(4, 2) because of Stack Overflow exception, it is not tail recursive. But it is not the most important point here. My problem is how to use both, State and TailRec

Comment: @BobDalgleish, I don't think you are right about memoization. As this code represents strictly sequential computation, state from previous branch is "inherited" by the next branch and memoization works OK. You can verify this by adding some logging to the `case None =>` branch and see that it is never called twice for the same `(m, n)` pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know at least in cats, `State[S, A]` is a type alias for `StateT[Eval, S, A]`, where `Eval` is analogous to `TailRec` in exactly the way you want - stack-safe delayed execution. This works just fine for me:

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._

type Memo = Map[(BigInt, BigInt), BigInt]

private[this] def a_impl(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): State[Memo, BigInt] = {
  if (m == 0) {
    State.pure(n + 1)
  } else {
    for {
      memoed <- State.inspect[Memo, Option[BigInt]](s => s.get((m, n)))
      res <- memoed match {
        case Some(x) => State.pure[Memo, BigInt](x)
        case None => {
          if (n == 0) for {
            a <- a_impl(m - 1, 1)
            _ <- State.modify[Memo](s => s + ((m, n) -> a))
          } yield a
          else for {
            a <- a_impl(m, n - 1)
            b <- a_impl(m - 1, a)
            _ <- State.modify[Memo](s => s + ((m, n) -> b))
          } yield b
        }
      }
    } yield res
  }
}

def a(m: BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  a_impl(m, n).runA(Map()).value
}
```

My guess is scalaz might have some similar `StateT` and `Eval` as well, though I'm not familiar with the library.